# regex pattern is matching with one of the pattern i cant able to follow?

Tags: java, regex, match

I just come across a regex pattern and its matching pattern strings, but i am confused about one of the matched pattern

```
Target: .50 1.50 0.50 10.50 00.50 1.555

Pattern: (0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d\d

Matches with: (4,7:1.50)(9,12:0.50)(14,18:10.50)(21,24:0.50)(26,29:1.55)
```

What i deduce from the pattern is two digit after decimal, and before decimal a group in which first digit is either  0 or any digit between 1 to 9, followed by empty string or any number string...

> I think in last second match it should be 00.50.

What am i missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think in last second match it should be 00.50.
>
> What am i missing??

No, this part of your regex `(0|[1-9]\d*)\.` can be rewritten as `(0\.|[1-9]\d*\.)`, so it can only accept

- one `0` and `.`

OR

- `[1-9]\d*` and `.`

If you want it to allow many zeroes before dot use

```
(0+|[1-9]\d*)\.\d\d
  ^--one or more zeroes
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your regex pattern to

```
(00?|[1-9]\d*)\.\d\d
```

if you want to allow either one or two zeroes before the decimal. The reason your current regex captures only a part of it is because the `|` says either capture one zero before `.` or capture a number of any length that doesn't start with a zero (because the class `[1-9]` excludes it).

Answer (score 1):

```
(0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d\d

^^
```

Your pattern says match `0 or any digit from 1 to 9 and then as many` .So the result is correct as you have not provided anchors or word boundaries to disallow partial matches.Use

```
\b(0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d\d\b
```

to make only proper matches.